# MVC - select correct dropdown option after jquery populating it

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating an editing view that will change its content and form elements based on the editing operations. I pass a model, store a value in a hidden element and then, once the document is ready, i use ajax to populate a dropdown. Immediately after that i need to select the right option that is equal to the value in the hidden element.
My code won't work and i've been trying to figure out why for 2 days.

**RAZOR**

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddl_publisher", new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control form-group", @style = "display:none", @onchange = "storeNewPublisher()" });
@Html.Hidden("hid_publisher", Model.Value, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadPublishers();
    changeDDLSelection();
}

function changeDDLSelection() {
    publ = $("#hid_publisher").val();
    $("#ddl_publisher").val(publ).change();
}
function storeNewPublisher() {
    var publisherText = $("#ddl_publisher option:selected").text();
    var publisherValue = $("#ddl_publisher option:selected").val();
    var publisherStatus = publisherText.replace(publisherValue, '').replace('-', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').trim();
    $("#hid_publisher").val(publisherValue);
    $("#hid_publisherStatus").val(publisherStatus);
}
```

**AJAX**

```
function loadPublishers() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Filter/GetPublishers/",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: { productType : $("#ddl_filterProdType option:selected").val() },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, pub) {
                $("#ddl_publisher").append('<option value="' + pub.Text + '"> [ ' + pub.Value + ' ] - ' + pub.Text + '</option>');
            });
         },
         error: displayPublishFailureMessage
     });
 }
```

The call succeedes, and inside *changeDDLSelection* the variable *publ* has the right value, but the dropdown won't change its option (it does it, instead, if i execute the code in Chrome console).
Yet, *change* fires, so *storeNewPublisher* is triggered but every local variable is *undefined*.

I can't bang my head on the wall more than this, my neighbours are complaining.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: ok, this actually worked together with the answer from Shyju! Thank you! I wonder why chaining the calls wouldn't do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current implementation, you are calling `changeDDLSelection` method after `loadPublishers`. But that does not mean that your second method will always execute after changeDDLSelection method finishes all the stuff it had to do. If you put a console.log in each method you will see this.

What you should be doing is, calling the `changeDDLSelection` method inside the `success` event of the ajax call for `loadPublishers` method (after appending all the options from the result array)

```
function loadPublishers() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Filter/GetPublishers/",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: { productType : $("#ddl_filterProdType option:selected").val() },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, pub) {
                $("#ddl_publisher").append('<option value="' + pub.Text +
                                   '"> [ ' + pub.Value + ' ] - ' + pub.Text + '</option>');
            });
            //Safely call the second method here
             changeDDLSelection();
         },
         error: displayPublishFailureMessage
     });
}
function changeDDLSelection() {
    var publ = $("#hid_publisher").val();
    $("#ddl_publisher").val(publ).change();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadPublishers();       
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that's where i put it first, but i ha the same result, and i thought that maybe, for some reason, it wasn't firing inside the success portion of the code.

Comment: It worked, together with the separated calls as suggested by Nadeem.
I thought the calls were sequential, not parallel! Many thanks!